# "Illegal byte sequence" in bash, how do I find it?

Tags: bash, vim

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to sort a text file on osx (bash):

```
sort: string comparison failed: Illegal byte sequence
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were ‘\363\272\331DR\371’ and ‘201310’.
```

The web is full of advice to set LC_ALL as the error recommends. However, I would like to find the location of this illegal byte sequence.

I'm parsing data from lots of third parties, doing all kinds of normalization before I write it to a single file, which is eventually uploaded to a database. There should be no fancy characters in this data and this error tells me that there is corruption somewhere in the process. However, I can't find it!

I have tried to 'split' the file into smaller and smaller pieces so I could visually find the character, but I can't. I can't grep it, find it in vim or in sublimetext.

Any ideas how I can find the locaiton of this corruption?

Comment: Looks like some not ASCII Characters are used somewhere.. maybe you could try to convert all input to UTF-8 before using it and set your environment accordingly?

Comment: How did you grep? `LC_ALL=C fgrep $'\363\272\331DR\371' yourinput`

Answer (score 1):

Does this one help you?

```
grep -n $(echo -e '\0363\0272\0331DR\0371') filename
```

To do things automatically you may consider modifying the source code

coreutils-8.23/lib/xmemcoll.c

```
static void
collate_error (int collation_errno,
               char const *s1, size_t s1len,
               char const *s2, size_t s2len)
{
  error (0, collation_errno, _("string comparison failed"));
  error (0, 0, _("Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem."));
  error (exit_failure, 0,
         _("The strings compared were %s and %s."),
         quotearg_n_style_mem (0, locale_quoting_style, s1, s1len),
         quotearg_n_style_mem (1, locale_quoting_style, s2, s2len));
}
```

At least this way you may easily write a trash-bin-file to put all those lines in for inspection.